# Migrating support to Android X: Are versions consistent across Modules?

Tags: android, migration, android-support-library, androidx

I am migrating a big project to AndroidX.

On my former project, on the top `build.gradle`, I have defined a variable with the support library version so the 30+ child `build.gradle`'s include the desired support version:

```
ext {
    supportLibraryVersion = "28.0.0"
    buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
    googleServicesVersion = "15.0.0"
}
```

My question is, now that I have run the Android X refactoring, I see that dependencies have been converted to different packages under the Android X namespace **and even out of it**:

```
    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
    implementation "androidx.percentlayout:percentlayout:1.0.0"
    implementation 'androidx.palette:palette:1.0.0'
   implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
```

My question is if now with Android X all module versions are synchronized so it makes sense doing in the top gradle:

```
ext {
    androidXLibraryVersion = "x.x.x"
}
```

My guess is that modules outside the Android X namespace will have their own version schedule, but I am not even sure that the modules under AndroidX namespace will use common versions.

What do you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the AndroidX world, every group (i.e., the part before the first `:` such as `androidx.appcompat`) can have a separate version as per the [AndroidX Overview](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx):

> Unlike the Support Library, AndroidX packages are separately maintained and updated. The androidx packages use strict [Semantic Versioning](https://semver.org/) starting with version 1.0.0. You can update AndroidX libraries in your project independently.

As seen on the [AndroidX releases page](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/), they absolutely do upgrade at different rates, but the semantic versioning requirement ensures that stable versions of the libraries will continue to work together.